# How to divide an images dataset into subsets depending on their names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, dataset, data-processing

I have a dataset called "Fingers" which I'm trying to build a TensorFlow model on...

However, I'm a little stuck, because I want to divide the images depending on the last 2  characters of the image's name (not including the extension).

like in the code below:

```
train_dir_list = os.listdir(train_set)
```

the train dir list contains some images of different names but the actual label that represents the image is at the end of the name as seen below:

> 123949**2L**.png 123123**5R**.png...

and so on...

the label of the image is located at index[-6:-5]
which R stands for RIGHT and L for LEFT. with the number for total fingers.

Now my problem is to divide those images into subdirectories as 1L, 2L... 5L, and 1R... 5R for each one to have its own directory, in order to use Keras ImageDataGenerator.

pls help and you can find the dataset on Kaggle names Fingers.

Answer (score 0):

1. keep all your images in a folder named `'imgs'`
2. Use glob to read all images, check their names.

```
import glob
import cv2

imgs = []
labels = []

for f in glob.glob('imgs/*.png'):
   imgs.append(cv2.imread(f))
   str_label = f.split('.')[0][-2:] # 5L / 3R

   if str_label[-1] == 'R':
       labels.append([int(str_label[-2]), 1]) # 1 denotes right
   else:
       labels.append([int(str_label[-2]), 0]) # 0 == left hand
```